# How can i add text on option text without remove values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I'm facing issues trying to add some text without changing values on option selection.

Could you please help me to face this issue?

I have this HTML CODE

```
<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
 <option value="name">     Name</option>
 <option value="lastanem1">First Lastname</option>
 <option value="lastname2">Second Lastname</option>
 ...
 <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Other value</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to add text to text options without removing the value.

```
<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
 <option value="name">     Filter by Name</option>
 <option value="lastanem1">Filter by First Lastname</option>
 <option value="lastname2">Filter by Second Lastname</option>
 ...
 <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Filter by Other value</option>
</select>
```

I tried this Jquery code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#q_c_0_a_0_name option[value=cont]").textContent  += "Filter by";
});
```

Also tried this Jquery code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#q_c_0_a_0_name option[value]").textContent  += "Filter by";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```js
$("#q_c_0_a_0_name option").text(function() {
  return "Filter by " + $(this).text()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
  <option value="name"> Name</option>
  <option value="lastanem1">First Lastname</option>
  <option value="lastname2">Second Lastname</option>
  <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Other value</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="q_c_0_a_0_name">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="lastanem1">First Lastname</option>
    <option value="lastname2">Second Lastname</option>
    <option value="xxxxxxxxx">Other value</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#q_c_0_a_0_name').find($('option').prepend('Filter By '));
</script>
```